# How do you get the method name being called from an event?

Tags: c#, reflection

My question is best described with a small code sample;

```
public class ClassA {
    public delegate void MyDelegate(EventArgs e);
    public event MyDelegate MyEvent;

    public void OnEvent(EventArgs e) {
        if (MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(e);
            // print "WhatIsMyName" here
    }
}

public class ClassB {

    public ClassB() {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.MyEvent += WhatIsMyName;
    }

    public static void WhatIsMyName(EventArgs e) {

    }
}
```

I'm guessing I need to use reflection but I'm not sure how to go about it (or even if it's possible). I'd also like to be able to get the class name of the method.

Comment: Why you need a class name here? You need to bind a method as a handler right?

Comment: What do you want if there are *multiple* handlers subscribed to the same event? What do you want if it's an anonymous delegate or lambda that's been subscribed? You might get better assistance if you can describe *why* you want/need to obtain this name - what's the overall goal here? One of the purposes of having events is so that e.g. `ClassA` doesn't have to *know* about other pieces of code that are interested in `MyEvent` occurring.

Comment: Note that you can have *any number* of subscribers to an event. So (assuming it was possible, which I don't think it is) you'd have to print a *list* of method names.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I'd like to get the method name for each subscriber and use it as a unique key for a cache. I could expose a property in ClassA to handle this but a generated key would automate the otherwise manual declaration. Having said that I am still interested in the answer from an academic perspective.

Comment: And if two subscribers happen to have named their methods identically?

Comment: I assumed I'd be able to distinguish them by class name as per my final statement? An identical method name with a different signature wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a new feature in .NET 4.5, which is called "Caller Information".

You can get some information about caller like that:

```
public void Foo([CallerMemberName]string sourceMemberName = "", 
                [CallerFilePath]string sourceFilePath = "", 
                [CallerLineNumber]int sourceLineNo = 0)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Member Name : " + sourceMemberName);
    Debug.WriteLine("File Name : " + sourceFilePath);
    Debug.WriteLine("Line No. : " + sourceLineNo);
}
```

More information:
[Caller Info - codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-caller-info-attributes-in-.net-4.5.htm)

Comment: But it looks like the OP is looking for the opposite of this - "I'm just about to/have just invoked a delegate - what's the name of function that I invoke(d)?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.aspx) class to look at the entire stack trace for your application. This will be quite slow, but should work.

Check out the [GetFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe.aspx) and [GetFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframes.aspx) methods for some examples.

Edit:
If you are on .Net 4.5 you might also use the [CallerMemberName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) attribute. This will be a faster and more elegant solution if it fits your requirements.